# Predict satisfaction score given a shift of Service Level Agreement

Tags: predictive-models, nonparametric, poisson-distribution, survey

I would like to make predictions for Overall Satisfaction based on a shift of Service Level Agreement (SLA).

I have `number of days` taken to complete a single service, and a `satisfaction score` (n=4000)

```
num_days   score
       1       5
       1       4
       2       5
       2       3
      10       1
```

The observed data is given SLA = 10 days. For those that are unaware of Service Level Agreements: this means that contractually a supplier promises to deliver a service/product within 10 days.

Please see the plot for illustrative purpose. The orange line is the average satsifaction per day and it has confidence bounds.

[image]

How can I predict the Overall Satisfaction for the whole data given that we would move the SLA to 9 days?

Some assumptions:

- The observed frequencies will "move" towards the left (but how to model it?)
- I expect the average satisfaction will get lower (or equal) for x=1 given SLA=9 compared to x=1 given SLA=10, since we are relatively slower

How can we estimate the shift of frequencies? I thought maybe I can use a poisson distribution but it is not a good fit. I also thought perhaps to fit a log/exp curve, but I am looking for someone who has knowledge how to theoretically do this.

In the end: what would we expect the total average satisfaction to be when we shift the SLA from 10 to 9?

EDIT: Maybe another useful image is to show the frequencies (x=num_days, y=frequency density)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a proportional odds logistic regression model? https://data.library.virginia.edu/fitting-and-interpreting-a-proportional-odds-model/   There are variations on this basic idea which may/may not be a better fit for your data.

The response variables are ordinal (1 to 5) and the predictor variables are quantitative (?).

I think Agresti wrote the definite book on this https://www.wiley.com/en-gb/Categorical+Data+Analysis%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780470463635, I don't know if you can find a copy of the relevant chapter if that helps?

I made a quick sketch as to how I understand it.   Your linear predictor for any value of time gives you a random latent variable which is sketched in red (sorry they're not very smooth, very rough sketch).  As you can see, the top "latent variable distribution" is to the right of the bottom "latent variable distribution".   The location of this latent variable distribution is specified by your linear predictor.

The cutpoints are sketched in grey.   Each zone delimeted by grey dotted lines corresponds to a different satisfaction score, from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, upwards.  From this, you can work out the probability that you get whichever score.   So you can assess quality of fit by whether this matches the number of responses in each box.   But you can also tell whether overall satisfaction has gone up or down

[image]

Comment: I am literally only using the 2 variables shown. It is fine to predict a continuous variable as I'm interested in predicting the average.

Comment: You could think about it as having a latent (hidden) continuous variable, which is satisfaction.   You have a regression model to predict satisfaction. Then you have cut-points which translate this latent variable into the five boxes.   This means you don't have to assume that your 1,2,3,4,5 scores are on a ratio scale.

Comment: I see, but how does that help with modeling the fact that we observe under SLA=10 days and want to somehow "predict" a distribution under SLA=9 (this is easier to imagine if the data would follow a poisson distribution)

Comment: Conceptually, you've estimated your cutpoints when fitting the model.   You estimate your "latent" variable ($\hat{y} = x^T \hat{\beta}$) at SLA=9 and apply the cutpoints to get your estimated scores.  But I think the software does that for you (or it might give you the log odds of an individual having sat=k at SLA=9 for each value of k).

Comment: I think in what I've shown, nothing has been done with anything related to SLA=9 yet... the observed frequencies and attached survey scores are belonging to SLA=10. It is possible to model average survey score based on number of days, but that would be given SLA=10. What I would like to do is predict the shift of frequencies when SLA=10 would move to 9. Maybe it is necessary to assume a model...

Comment: Let's say we would assume it would follow a Poisson distribution (it's a bad fit), then it might be possible to find lambda and somehow shift it...

Comment: I added another image to show the frequencies observed under SLA=10. I'd expect the mass to shift a bit to the left under SLA=9, but I am not sure what the approach would be to estimate this in a non-parametric way (or at least you can see that Poisson is a bad fit).